# R no method for coercing S4 class to a vector BioConductor AnnotationDbi package

Tags: r, r-s4, bioconductor

I have in code a method call:

```
> MYOBJECT
PATHID2NAME map for KEGG (object of class "AnnDbBimap")
```

I am running somebody else's function and getting an error

```
>as.list.default(MYOBJECT) : 
 no method for coercing this S4 class to a vector
```

I can see that in the source code for the function that what is actually being called is

```
as.list(MYOBJECT)
```

My hunch is that R is not using the correct as.list function due to possibly some namespace error. How do I manually import the as.list from AnnotationDbi and force R to use it instead of whatever S3 method it's calling?

Comment: Why not use `as.list(MYOBJECT)` instead of forcing `as.list.default(MYOBJECT)` ?

Comment: @thelatemail thanks for the reply, it is actually called in a function not written by me

Comment: You could potentially overwrite the function temporarily, like `as.list.default <- as.list`, but that's probably quite unstable and might stuff things up.

Comment: @thelatemail is there a way for me to say to R "hey, import the as.list  method for this object from this package and use it instead of trying to use your default"  

I ask because otherwise I don't know how to get the correct as.list method. (see my edited question), thanks again!

Comment: If you use `as.list`, R should, if defined in loaded package, use the appropriate method to coerce the object to list.